# <br> is not being applied in mat-expansion-panel-header

Tags: angular, angular-material

[The Image shows how break is not being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4i9J.png)

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
   <mat-expansion-panel-header [collapsedHeight]="'70px'">
      <mat-panel-title>
         <span class="Text">Room 03</span><br>
        <span class="link" style="opacity:0.7">A/C</span>
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        <span class="link" style="opacity:0.7">Beds Available</span><br>
        <span class="Text">2/4</span><br>
      </mat-panel-description>
   </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

In this code the 
 tag is not being applied. please check the image AT THE START OF THE QUESTION. I want A/C and 2/4 to come to the next line.

Answer (score 4):

Remove all the `<br>` tags and add this to your components CSS file:

```
mat-panel-title,
mat-panel-description,
span {
  display: block;
}
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-vis985?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
>   is a working stackblitz.

Comment: Hey it worked after I added a <div> tag and included the span tag in it. Thank you.

Comment: This pointed me into the right direction, thanks. I would suggest to use .mat-expansion-panel-header .mat-content instead of the generic span selector.